# How to turn off SSLCompression in Apache 2.2.12 on Amazon EC2?

Tags: apache-2.2, amazon-ec2, https

I am on an Amazon EC2, Suse installation which comes with a Apache 2.2.12. I am using HTTPS and want to turn off SSLCompression but it isn't available for Apache 2.2.12. I can't even upgrade Apache as the repository maintained by Amazon doesn't yet include Apache 2.4.3, not even Apache 2.2.24.

So since I'm stuck with it, is there anyway I can turn off SSLCompression in Apache 2.2.12?

Comment: See related, which has an answer based on the bug report on redhat.com : http://serverfault.com/questions/455450/how-to-disable-sslcompression-on-apache-httpd-2-2-15-defense-against-crime-bea

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no option to disable compression in Apache <= 2.2.23 mod_ssl.

You have few options to resolve this problem:

> 1) Wait for Apache 2.2.24 and compile from source:
>   https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=53219
>
> 2) Use current stable Apache 2.2.23 and use patch for disabling compression
>   from the link above
>
> 3) Use other frontend/proxy for SSL termination (for
>   example nginx or pound)

Comment: I didn't wanted to install from an external source as resolving the dependencies would have been a pain. Anyways, I opted for the Amazon AMI(based on RedHat) and the repository it came with had Apache2.4 so I guess am good with it now.