# How to disable SSLCompression on Apache httpd 2.2.15? (Defense against CRIME/BEAST)

Tags: apache-2.2, security, tls, mod-ssl

I read about the [CRIME](https://community.qualys.com/blogs/securitylabs/2012/09/14/crime-information-leakage-attack-against-ssltls) attack against TLS Compression ([CVE-2012-4929](http://web.nvd.nist.gov/view/vuln/detail?vulnId=CVE-2012-4929), CRIME is a successor to the BEAST attack against ssl & tls), and I want to protect my webservers against this attack by [disabling SSL Compression](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/19911/crime-how-to-beat-the-beast-successor), which was added to Apache 2.2.22 (See [Bug 53219](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=53219)).

I am running Scientific Linux 6.3, which ships with httpd-2.2.15. Security fixes for upstream versions of httpd 2.2 should be backported to this version.

```
# rpm -q httpd
httpd-2.2.15-15.sl6.1.x86_64

# httpd -V
Server version: Apache/2.2.15 (Unix)
Server built:   Feb 14 2012 09:47:14
Server's Module Magic Number: 20051115:24
Server loaded:  APR 1.3.9, APR-Util 1.3.9
Compiled using: APR 1.3.9, APR-Util 1.3.9
```

I tried [SSLCompression off](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_ssl.html#sslcompression) in my configuration, but that results in the following error message:

```
# /etc/init.d/httpd restart
Stopping httpd:                                            [  OK  ]
Starting httpd: Syntax error on line 147 of /etc/httpd/httpd.conf:
Invalid command 'SSLCompression', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
                                                           [FAILED]
```

Is it possible to disable SSLCompression with this version of Apache Webserver?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

On March 4, 2013, [Red Hat provided updated OpenSSL packages which address this issue](https://rhn.redhat.com/errata/RHSA-2013-0587.html). You can receive them through your normal update channels.

The original answer was:

---

[Red Hat has not provided an updated package which provides this functionality](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=857051), though there is a workaround available. Edit the `/etc/sysconfig/httpd` file and add this line to it:

```
export OPENSSL_NO_DEFAULT_ZLIB=1
```

Then restart Apache:

```
service httpd restart
```

This will cause OpenSSL, which provides crypto functions for Apache, to not offer compression.

Comment: What about mod_deflate? Shouldn't that be disabled as well?

Comment: No, that's irrelevant.