# Disable SSL / TLS compression in Apache 2.2.x

Tags: apache-2.2, security, ssl, tls, mod-ssl

Is there a way to disable SSL/TLS Compression in Apache 2.2.x when using mod_ssl?

If not, what are people doing to mitigate the effects of CRIME/BEAST in older browsers?

Related Links:

1. https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=53219
2. https://threatpost.com/en_us/blogs/new-attack-uses-ssltls-information-leak-hijack-https-sessions-090512
3. https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/19911/crime-how-to-beat-the-beast-successor

Comment: Also see http://serverfault.com/questions/455450/how-to-disable-sslcompression-on-apache-httpd-2-2-15-defense-against-crime-bea

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use [`SSLCompression off` if you're on 2.2.24 or later](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_ssl.html#sslcompression).

If not, you can set the `OPENSSL_NO_DEFAULT_ZLIB` environment variable to force compression off in OpenSSL - see [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/455450/how-to-disable-sslcompression-on-apache-httpd-2-2-15-defense-against-crime-bea).